# Rigorous definition of a function whose input is a set

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we have an $f: \mathbb A \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n}  $ with $ \mathbb A \subseteq \mathbb R^{m} $. Some authors, in order to write down the set of outputs for a given set of inputs, say $ P $,  write $f(P)$. I guess what they mean is:

$$ f(P) = \{ z\in\mathbb R^{n}|z=f(x) \ for \ x\in P\} $$
But is that really allowed? The inputs of $f$ should only be members of $\mathbb A $, not entire sets. It seems to me as a symbolic notation. Is there something more rigorous out there? (something that might involve a set function maybe ?)

Comment: That's the definition of the image of $P$ under $f$. Since it's the set of all $f(p)$ with $p \in P$ it makes sense to denote it with the notation $f(P)$. But of course the symbol $f(P)$ wouldn't make sense until we give it that meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most circumstances, we make this definition and it causes no problems.

But in some circumstances, you want to distinguish these two things.  If $f : X \to Y$ is a function, you may defined an "induced function" connecting the power sets $ f^* : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$.